# How can i access current woocommerce order shipping method id?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have found method

```
$order->get_shipping_method()
```

to access the name, but i want to retrieve the id instead of name?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

thought i'd share how I solved this if someone runs into the same problem as me. I have WC_Order in the $order variable.

```
$order->get_items( 'shipping' );
```

This gives me an array with name, type, method_id, cost and taxes.

Comment: Hey how did you figure this out?  Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: How did you then retived only the method_id?

Comment: `$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );`inside your method, hope it helps.

Comment: `reset( $order->get_items( 'shipping' ) )->get_method_id();` does the trick, if you need to get id only. `get_items()` gives you associative array of shipping items. `reset()` takes first item of this array, that is `WC_Order_Item_Shipping`. And finally `get_method_id()` gets id (eg. `local_pickup:42`).

Answer (score 7):

```
$shipping_method = @array_shift($order->get_shipping_methods());
$shipping_method_id = $shipping_method['method_id'];
```

Comment: Thanks. I print_r($shipping_method) , and used 'method_title' instead since that's what I needed. I was messed up on the indexing here until I saw your array_shift.

Comment: Why do you use "@" with array_shift function ?

Comment: @ZecKa I think it was copy-paste. But generally shipping methods can be empty.