# Get chosen shipping method title by its Id in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce `includes\class-express-checkout-gateway.php` file I am getting shipping method Id by the following code:

```
$chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods');
```

It gets `flat_rate:1`, but I need its title - `Flat Rate`.

I have already tried all this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126438/how-can-i-access-current-woocommerce-order-shipping-method-id) and many more.

How can I get this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the shipping method title from its method rate ID in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47477272/get-the-shipping-method-title-from-its-method-rate-id-in-woocommerce)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$rate_table = array();

$shipping_methods = WC()->shipping->get_shipping_methods();

foreach($shipping_methods as $shipping_method){
    $shipping_method->init();

    foreach($shipping_method->rates as $key=>$val)
        $rate_table[$key] = $val->label;
}

echo $rate_table[WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0]];
```

Try like this

Comment: @developersaumya : Try printing $rate_table. Check it contains the data

Comment: $rate_table is blank

Comment: includes\class-express-checkout-gateway.php woocommerce express checkout

Comment: Try just printing $shipping_methods

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146139/discussion-between-developersaumya-and-mujeebu-rahman).

Comment: Thank you, this is working!

Comment: @mujuonly I think this is no longer working in new WooCommerce - can you check?

Answer (score 5):

If the customer has calculated the shipping on the front end, this should work:

```
function get_shipping_name_by_id( $shipping_id ) {
    $packages = WC()->shipping->get_packages();

    foreach ( $packages as $i => $package ) {
        if ( isset( $package['rates'] ) && isset( $package['rates'][ $shipping_id ] ) ) {
            $rate = $package['rates'][ $shipping_id ];
            /* @var $rate WC_Shipping_Rate */
            return $rate->get_label();
        }
    }

    return '';
}
```

This will return an empty string if it couldn't find a name for the given shipping id.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the **same shipping method twice**, for example two different local_pickup, then the previous methods do NOT work.

*(we had to use one local_pickup for 'real' local pickup, and the other one for customers who picked up their food at the counter to eat it on the premises)*

To get the information for each instance of local_pickup, you can read it directly from the options table in the db with this method:

```
/**
 * Assuming you have the $shipping_method_id in the form of 'local_pickup:2' for example.
 * @param $shipping_method_id
 * @return false
 */
function get_shipping_method_settings_from_method_id( $shipping_method_id = '' ){
    if( ! empty( $shipping_method_id ) ){
        // create the options key
        $method_key_id = str_replace( ':', '_', $shipping_method_id );
        // Get the complete option slug
        $option_name = 'woocommerce_'.$method_key_id.'_settings';
        // retrieve the entry from the options and return the array
        return get_option( $option_name, true );
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

(adapted from this [wp-qa](https://wp-qa.com/get-the-shipping-method-title-from-its-method-rate-id-in-woocommerce) post)

Comment: looks like the accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47477272/get-the-shipping-method-title-from-its-method-rate-id-in-woocommerce

Comment: @Fanky as you can see above, i got it from wp-qa, no idea where they got it from or who used their answer :)

Answer (score 0):

None of above works for me. So I dig in woocommerce core and here's the code:

```
$chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get("chosen_shipping_methods");
function get_shipping_name_by_id( $chosen_shipping_methods ) {
        if(preg_match("/\d+/", $chosen_shipping_methods, $instance_id)){
            $shipping_method = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_shipping_method( $instance_id[0] );
            return $shipping_method->get_title();
        }
        return null;
    }

$shipping_method_name = get_shipping_name_by_id(chosen_shipping_methods);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$current_shipping_method = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
$packages = WC()->shipping()->get_packages();
$package = $packages[0];
$available_methods = $package['rates'];
foreach ($available_methods as $key => $method) {
    if($current_shipping_method[0] == $method->id){
        echo $method->label;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).