# Get the shipping method title from its method rate ID in Woocommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have my custom function who retrieves id of each shipping method id (ex `flat_rate:3`)

I need to retrieve the method title by the id (as the image below, I need :

> Fast Shipping

[image: shipping method title]

According to the doc, I found `WC_Shipping_Method::get_method_title()` but I can't retrieve by id.

Also saw that shipping method label is stored in the `wp_options` table with `option_id`, so can't manage to do SQL request.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update 2** *(Simplified function code)*

To retrieve the shipping method title from it's complete ID (Method Rate ID), it can be done with that simple and lightweight custom function:

```
function get_title_shipping_method_from_method_id( $method_rate_id = '' ){
    if( ! empty( $method_rate_id ) ){
        $method_key_id = str_replace( ':', '_', $method_rate_id ); // Formating
        $option_name = 'woocommerce_'.$method_key_id.'_settings'; // Get the complete option slug
        return get_option( $option_name, true )['title']; // Get the title and return it
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.

---

**Usage example** *(output the Shipping method title)*:

```
// Define the Shipping Method rate ID example
$method_rate_id = 'flat_rate:3';

// Get the title and display it
$title = get_title_shipping_method_from_method_id( $method_rate_id );
echo '<p>' . $title . '</p>';
```

It will displays your custom shipping method title

Comment: Hi, I already try this SQL request, it's not what I did. I'll edit my question

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll contact you soon. I put it here for somebody else find too

Comment: Ohh I didn't think we could use `get_option()` function like that ! Thanks @LoicTheAztec