# WooCommerce /order-received shipping method title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

everyone!
To cut a long story short, on my /order-received page (a "Thank You" page) I've got a shipping class displayed, rather than actual shipping method title I put in admin panel.
For instance, it's displaying "Flat Rate" instead of "Abracadabra."
In the Checkout template itself I used following piece of code to solve the problem:

```
<?php echo $shipping_method->get_title(); ?>
```

And it worked like magic. When I tried to change code for /order-received page (/woocommerce/templates/order/order-details.php), however, I found myself stuck to this:

```
<tfoot>
        <?php
            foreach ( $order->get_order_item_totals() as $key => $total ) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                    <td><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
        ?>
    </tfoot>
```

Just got stuck here. I know it should be somewhere here but it isn't. Would be eternally grateful for any help. Thx. P.S. I'd also like to know how to fix this issue in terms of e-mails a customer receives after having completed an order. Many thanks in advance again.

Comment: Maybe see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26174867/383847